# Can I improve oci8 performance using PHP7?

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, ubuntu, php-7, oci8

My tools are as follows

- Ubuntu server 16
- PHP7
- oci8
- codeigniter
- Oracle DB

I have php7 with oci8 successfully running by installing the basic and devel .rpm files from oracle's website.

I'm able to successfully connect to my oracle database and return data through my webpage.

The issue I'm having is the time to execute the query is about twice as long as it is on my PRD server that is using an ODBC connection and a driver from actual oracle on OS X (Mac). I'm not sure why the performance would be twice as slow. Especially considering this server's hardware capabilities are much more powerful.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: After actually measuring the execution times alone, it looks like they truly are faster on the new server. The page load seems to be slower because of codeigniter's oci8 driver, I'd have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

DRCP Connection Pooling

PHP from 5.3 (PECL OCI8 1.3) supports Oracle Database Resident Connection Pooling (DRCP). DRCP allows more efficient use of database machine memory and provides high scalability. No, or minimal, application changes are needed to use DRCP.

DRCP is suited for applications that connect using few database schemas and hold database connections open for a short period of time. Other applications should use Oracle's default Dedicated database server processes, or use Shared servers.

DRCP benefits all three connection functions, but gives the highest scalability when connections are created with oci_pconnect().

For DRCP to be available in OCI8, Oracle client libraries used by PHP and the version of the Oracle Database must both be 11g or greater.

Documentation on DRCP is found in several Oracle manuals. For example, see » Configuring Database Resident Connection Pooling in the Oracle documentation for usage information. A » DRCP white paper contains background information on DRCP.

To use DRCP, build PHP with the OCI8 1.3 (or later) extension and Oracle 11g (or later) libraries and then follow these steps:

```
As a privileged database administrator, use a program like SQL*Plus to start the connection pool in the database:

    SQL> execute dbms_connection_pool.start_pool;

Optionally use dbms_connection_pool.alter_param() to configure DRCP settings. The current pool settings can be queried from the DBA_CPOOL_INFO view.

Update the connection strings used. For PHP applications that currently connect using a Network Connect Name like MYDB:

    $c = oci_pconnect("myuser", "mypassword", "MYDB");

modify the tnsnames.ora file and add a (SERVER=POOLED) clause, for example:

    MYDB = (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp) (HOST=myhost.dom.com)
           (PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales)
           (SERVER=POOLED)))

Alternatively, modify the Easy Connect syntax in PHP and add :POOLED after the service name:

    $c = oci_pconnect("myuser", "mypassword", "myhost.dom.com:1521/sales:POOLED");

Edit php.ini and choose a connection class name. This name indicates a logical division of the connection pool and can be used to isolate pooling for separate applications. Any PHP applications with the same user name and connection class value will be able to share connections in the pool, giving greater scalability.

    oci8.connection_class = "MY_APPLICATION_NAME"

Run the application, connecting to the 11g (or later) database.
```

Comment: This looks like a great starting point. Thanks

Comment: @magowan90 my pleasure! http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.connection.php

Comment: DRCP is for scalability when the DB host machine doesn't have enough memory to handle the workload.  There is nothing in @magowan90's question to indicate that is the problem.

Comment: Try and identify what is slow(er).  If it is establishing a connection - make sure you use oci_pconnect().  If it is a query, tune the SQL and look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-prefetch.php  You could do worse than the check the tips second half of http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html